# $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i)-1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i/\delta)-1} \stackrel{\text{?}}{\le} \frac{(1+x_n)^n-1}{(1+x_n/\delta)^n-1} $ .

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, fractions

Let $x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n$. Let $\delta>1$ be some positive real numbers. I assume that $0\le x_i <1$, for $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $x_n >0$.

Does the following expression hold?

$$ \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i)-1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i/\delta)-1} \stackrel{\text{?}}{\le} \frac{(1+x_n)^n-1}{(1+x_n/\delta)^n-1} $$

Comment: Any preliminary results?

Comment: Using a simple example in  Mathematica, it seems the expression holds: Reduce[ {((1 + x) (1 + y) - 1)/((1 + x/d) (1 + y/d) - 
    1) <= ( (1 + y)^2 - 1)/( (1 + y/d)^2 - 1), d > 1, 
  0 <= x  <= y < 1}, {x, y}]

Comment: Simplify[ {((1 + x) (1 + y) (1 + z) - 
    1)/((1 + x/d) (1 + y/d) (1 + z/d) - 1) <= ( (1 + z)^3 - 
    1)/( (1 + z/d)^3 - 1), d > 1, 0 <= x  <= y <= z < 1}, {x, y, z}]

Comment: This is how I would envision the proof (I don't have time to compute it myself right now): check if $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i)\stackrel{\text{?}}{\le}(1+x_n)^n$   $\forall n$. check if $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i/\delta)\stackrel{\text{?}}{\le}(1+x_n/\delta)^n$ $\forall n$. This will yield a relation for both the numerator and demonitator. Then you will be able to bound both of these inequalities from the definition of $\{x_i\}$, which will allow you to take the ratio and choose the proper inequality.

Comment: The two conditions you specified are always true because $x_n$ is the maximum, but  are not sufficient to prove the claim.

Comment: any progress or you are still at the 'conjecture' stage?? I'm curious about the result

Comment: No progress yet. Btw, thank you for setting some bounty ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By putting:
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+x_i),\quad A_\delta=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+x_i/\delta),$$
$$B=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+x_n),\quad B_\delta=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+x_n/\delta),$$
the inequality is equivalent to:
$$e^{A+B_\delta}+e^{A_\delta}+e^{B}\leq e^{B+A_\delta}+e^{A}+e^{B_\delta}.$$
Provided that $A+B_\delta\leq B+A_\delta$, the latter follows from [Karamata's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality).

So we have only to show that:
$$ B-A \geq B_\delta-A_\delta, \tag{1}$$
i.e.
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(\frac{1+x_n}{1+x_i}\right)\geq \sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(\frac{\delta+x_n}{\delta+x_i}\right).\tag{2}$$
This is quite trivial since for any $1>C>D>0$ the function $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x+C}{x+D}\right)$ is positive and decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$ since its derivative is $\frac{D-C}{(x+C)(x+D)}<0$, $f(0)>0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0.$

Comment: Nice proof, but I can't connect the stated inequality and the exponential form

Comment: @JGab: Just lift the denominators, move things around so you have only pluses, and use $e^{\log x}=x$.

Comment: I dont see why $B-A \ge B_\delta - A_\delta$ is sufficient to complete the proof. We want to show $e^B - e^A \le e^{B_\delta} - e^{A_\delta}$ right?

Comment: We want to fulfill the hypothesis of the Karamata inequality, i.e., by considering that $e^x$ is a convex function, verify that $A+B_\delta\leq B+A_\delta$, $A+B_\delta+A_\delta\leq B+A_\delta+A$ (this is trivial since $B_\delta\leq B$) and $A+B_\delta+A_\delta+B=B+A_\delta+A+B_\delta$ (trivial, again).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you very much. This inequality is amazing!